# How can I modify JIRA's "Quick Search"?

Tags: filter, jira

How can I modify JIRA's `Quick Search` filter?

Currently it defaults to searching only `summary`, `description`, and `comment`:

```
summary ~ xxxxx OR description ~ xxxxx OR comment ~ xxxxx
```

I want it to search another field too. It's a simple add on to the current search:

```
summary ~ xxxxx OR description ~ xxxxx OR comment ~ xxxxx OR new_field ~ xxxxx
```

I am aware I can save my own searches as a filter, but can I edit, specifically, the `Quick Search` at the top right of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add an abritrary field to quick search, but the Quick Search feature does support shortcut strings which will query commonly-required data from other fields.  [See the JIRA docs.](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Using+Quick+Search#UsingQuickSearch-SmartQuerying)

Comment: Awesome. I've tried a lot of those shortcuts, but none are quite what I want. Is there a **search all fields** shortcut? It would be great to type in something like (keep in mind this will not work for anyone else reading) `all:xxxxx` and find all cases that contain "xxxxx".

Comment: All the available fields are listed in the Atlassian docs, but I wouldn't be surprised if they are easy to extend.  I would ask Atlassian support, they're pretty good.

Comment: @garethbowles, this is a custom field I need access to.

Comment: @garethbowles, is there a way to access all fields, including custom built fields?

Comment: Just kidding! I suspect this is not provided because it would be a query with a heavy load. You could create a JQL plugin that added a function to search for text in all fields that have a suitable searcher associated with them. Not simple though.